# Getting Multiple Object in AWS S3 with JS Promise All - Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, es6-promise

I am trying to get multiple images from AWS S3 by looping But I couldn't return more than one image data from that loop

**Fetching single image**

```
const getImage = async (imgKay) => {
    let tempImage = null;
    if (imgKay !== "default-header.jpg") {
       tempImage = await s3.getObject({Key: imgKay, Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}).promise();
    }
    return tempImage;
}
```

**Getting multiple objects by looping**

```
const loopAllImageAndAddToList = (blockContent) => {
    console.log("Data fetching please wait");
    let imgList = new Array();
    blockContent.forEach(async (bc, bcIdx, arrNum) => {
        console.log("index: " + bcIdx + " Array Length: ", arrNum.length);
        if (bc.blockElement.name === "imgBlockContent") {
            const tempImage = await getImage(bc.blockElement.imgUrl);
            imgList.push({ key: bc.blockElement.imgUrl, binaryImg: tempImage.Body });
        }
    });


    return Promise.all(imgList);
}
```

**Express get request**

```
router.get('/preview/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = `SELECT id, title, bg_img, bg_color, link_color, layout, content, sibling FROM nodejs_story WHERE id=?`;

    conn.query(sql, [req.params.id], async (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        try {
            const blockContent = await JSON.parse(result[0].content);
            const res = await loopAllImageAndAddToList(blockContent)
                console.log("res: ", res);
            res.render('template/template-preview', { docs: result[0] });
        } catch (readFileErr) {
            console.log("Read file error: ".red, readFileErr);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the return value from loopAllImageAndAddToList()?

Comment: I tried this also still getting blank array  ``` const res = await loopAllImageAndAddToList(blockContent)
                console.log("res: ", res); ```

Answer (score 1):

This way it's working

```
const loopAllImageAndAddToList = async () => {
    return Promise.all(imgKeys.map((img, index) => {
        console.log("Image: ", img);
        return getImage(img)
            .then(imgUrl => {
                // console.log("Returning from get image: ", imgUrl);
                return {
                    imgId: index + 1,
                    imgBfr: imgUrl
                }
            })
    }));
```

Comment: This way of doing it is better than Mestre's since you'll get the benefit of multitasking, whereas his will resolve the getImage() promises sequentially. You can probably benchmark it and see, but this is a very idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: The proposed solution is not taking into consideration something that seems to be important in the original question, the condition `if (bc.blockElement.name === "imgBlockContent")` which cannot be achieved with a direct map.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of code clarity/simplicity (which was my first answer's focus) you want the performance of the *concurrency* (not multitasking) an alternate, and more clear code could be something like this:

```js
const loopAllImageAndAddToList = async (blockContent) => {
  const imgList = [];
  for (const bc of blockContent)
    if (bc.blockElement.name === "imgBlockContent")
      imgList.push(getImage(bc.blockElement.imgUrl)
       .then(temp => ({ key: bc.blockElement.imgUrl, binaryImg: temp.Body }))


  return Promise.all(imgList);
}
```

Or if you are into the chaining code and don't like to use the `return` statements:

```js
const loopAllImageAndAddToList = async (blockContent) => Promise.all(
  blockContent.reduce((imgList, bc) =>
    bc.blockElement.name !== 'imgBlockContent'
      ? imgList
      : imgList.concat(
        getImage(bc.blockElement.imgUrl)
          .then(temp => ({ key: bc.blockElement.imgUrl, binaryImg: temp.Body }))
      ), [])
)
```

Comment: I went with your first answer.  I think that was the better option. I'd like to do multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using async/await it is simples to keep using that and not use `Promise.all` at all. Just replace the `forEach` with a simple for loop.

You can use a `for of` for example:

```js
const loopAllImageAndAddToList = (blockContent) => {
  console.log("Data fetching please wait");
  const imgList = new Array();
  for (const bc of blockContent) {
    if (bc.blockElement.name === "imgBlockContent") {
      const tempImage = await getImage(bc.blockElement.imgUrl);
      imgList.push({ key: bc.blockElement.imgUrl, binaryImg: tempImage.Body });
    }
  }


  return imgList;
}
```